# How do I find all gems which have a runtime dependency on a certain gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, dependencies

How do I find all gems which have a runtime dependency on a certain gem.

```
e.g. How do I find all gems which are dependent on mongoid gem version 2.3.4
```

Comment: All the gems installed on your computer, or all gems listed by rubygems.org?

Answer (score 3):

You use the `-R` (uppercase R) switch with `gem dependency`:

```
gem dependency mongoid -v '2.3.4' -R
```

outputs:

```
Gem mongoid-2.3.4
  activemodel (~> 3.1)
  bson_ext (~> 1.3, development)
  mocha (~> 0.9.12, development)
  mongo (~> 1.3)
  rdoc (~> 3.5.0, development)
  rspec (~> 2.6, development)
  tzinfo (~> 0.3.22)
  watchr (~> 0.6, development)
```

Comment: Is it possible to do so from within a .rb file as well?

Comment: This only works for local gems depending on mongoid.  It looks like OP is looking for how to list all gems on Rubygems depending on mongoid.

Answer (score 0):

```
gem dependency mongoid -v 2.3.4
```

Documentation here http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/10#page78

Comment: I think OP is asking the opposite: what gems depend ON mongoid.

Comment: Thanks @jwfeam. I am looking for dependencies in the reverse direction.